# PHPSpec does not call the method of the subject

Tags: php, phpspec

The following is the phpspec code I have

```
function it_throws_if_raw_data_xml_is_invalid()
{
    $website = $this->buildWebsite("some-deterministic-id", "some-deterministic-name");

    $this->convertAdwordsRawData($website, "yesterday", "invalidXML");

    $this->shouldThrow(AdwordsResponseNotParseable::class)
        ->during("convertAdwordsRawData", [$website, "yesterday", "invalid-xml"]);
}
```

The test fails, but not because the logic is wrong, but because `convertAdwordsRawData` never gets called. I added var_dump in it and it does not show up, while output from the constructor goes through. I tried to pass string instead of a $website, and got a typehint problem. If I just call the method inside the test without assertion, it never calls the method and passes the test, without outputting anything from var_dump. TO summarise, phpspec just does not execute the method for me. One test above it, that tests the same public method, works just fine.

What could be wrong here?

For the argument sake, consider the method does the following

```
public function convertAdwordsRawData(Websites $website, string $time, string $rawData): \Generator
    {
        var_dump("Here I am");
        throw new AdwordsResponseNotParseable($rawData);
        yield from [1,2,3,4,5];
    }
```

**Update**
Okay, so it all comes down to how php handles generators. The method call will return me an iterator that is not yet initialised. When I call the method on the actually returned generator, PHP will run everything up until the first yield on the first iteration, and return the yield on any consecutive iteration.

From php.net website

> When a generator function is called for the first time, an object of
>   the internal Generator class is returned. This object implements the
>   Iterator interface

`$this->convertAdwordsRawData(...)->shouldThrow(...)->duringCurrent();`

is the solution. current() call comes from implementation of Iterator in PHP - this method would be called on every iteration

Comment: It's hard to spot what is going wrong inside your function without looking at them. But try to set a breakpoint in xdebug, then step the execution to find out what went wrong. XDebug is a really quick, powerful and helpful tool to debug these kind of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem is not in the function, the problem is in the phpspec itself. The method does not get called at all. I could use xDebug to traverse through internals of phpspec, but to honest I was hoping it will not come to this

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
function it_throws_if_raw_data_xml_is_invalid(Websites $website)
{
    $this->shouldThrow(AdwordsResponseNotParseable::class)
    ->during("convertAdwordsRawData", [$website, "yesterday", "invalid-xml"]);    

}
```

More info: http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/cookbook/matchers.html#throw-matcher

Comment: This is exactly what I had. Apparently the problem was my understating of how PHP handles iterations, I though that the initialisation code (until the first yield) will be executed. But PHP does it only on the first iteration